# Plotly Express: Addressing Subplots

Tags: python, html, plotly, subplot, plotly-python

After having searched the web for hours now, I am absolutely frustrated and confused on how to address **subplots** with `plotly express` in **Python**.

My idea is to plot a line plot side-by-side with a scatter plot and a line plot and define the **labels**, **hover data**, etc. individually + add shapes and text to them.

What I came up with so far, however, uses `make_subplots` and only accepts traces.
Hence, all formatting of the `plotly.express` figures is being lost in the subplots!

I only found a way to change the axis limits of the individual subplots but not how to add a customized hover template, x-labels, y-labels, etc.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# CREATE 2 PLOTS with PLOTY EXPRESS ----------------------------------------------------
## fig 1 is a time series of two properties "type"
fig1 = px.line(df, x="year", y="total", color="type", title="layout.hovermode='x'")

fig1.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", hovertemplate=None)
fig1.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")

fig1.add_shape(type="line",
               x0=2016,
               y0=0,
               x1=2016,
               y1=800,
               line=dict(
                   color="gray",
                   width=2,
                   dash="dot"))

## fig2 is a cross-plot of two properties "type"

fig2 = px.scatter(data_frame=df,
                  x='activity_2011_2015', y='activity_2016_2020',
                  #size='costs',
                  color='type')

# add x=y line
fig2.add_shape(type="line",
               x0=0,
               y0=0,
               x1=600,
               y1=600,
               line=dict(
                   color="gray",
                   width=2,
                   dash="dot"))

# CREATE 1x2 SUBPLOTS ----------------------------------------------------
fig1_traces = []
fig2_traces = []


for trace in range(len(fig1["data"])):
    fig1_traces.append(fig1["data"][trace])
for trace in range(len(fig2["data"])):
    fig2_traces.append(fig2["data"][trace])


sub_fig = sp.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                           subplot_titles=['time series', 'cross-plot'],
                           horizontal_spacing=0.1)

for traces in fig1_traces:
    sub_fig.append_trace(traces, row=1, col=1)
for traces in fig2_traces:
    sub_fig.append_trace(traces, row=1, col=2)

## Address x axis and y axis range of first figure -----------------------------
sub_fig.update_layout(xaxis1 = dict(
    tickmode = 'array',
    range=[2015,2020],
    tickvals = np.arange(2015, 2020, 1).tolist())
)


sub_fig.show()
sub_fig.write_html("sub_fig.html", include_plotlyjs="cdn")
```

- **How can I address individual figures and their elements in the subplots?** I want to add the shapes back, add customized hover data and format X and Y axes individually because the plots do not have the same units...
- If this is not possible, can this code be recreated differently? All I want is two plots, side-by-side and interact with them...

[image: This is how the subplots shall look like]

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- It's just about being systematic. Each sub-plot *facet* uses its own axes.
- Hence to copy shapes into an integrated layout, you need to put them against appropriate axes

```
for t in fig1.data:
    sub_fig.add_trace(t, row=1, col=1)
for t in fig2.data:
    sub_fig.add_trace(t, row=1, col=2)

    
for s in fig1.to_dict()["layout"]["shapes"]:
    sub_fig.add_shape(s)

for s in fig2.to_dict()["layout"]["shapes"]:
    sub_fig.add_shape({**{"xref":"x2", "yref":"y2"}, **s})


sub_fig
```

[image]

#### data frame simulation

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"year":np.tile(range(2010,2010+10),2), "total":np.random.randint(300,800,20), "type":np.repeat(["a","b"],10),
                  'activity_2011_2015':np.random.randint(0,600,20), 'activity_2016_2020':np.random.randint(0,600,20)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This by and large answers the question but how can I a) preserve the hover-style of fig1, b) change the figure sizes (e.g. make fig1 wider than fig2) and finally c) change the x/y axes labels individually?